# Select column ComboBox Qt

Tags: sql, qt, combobox

I have a push buttton in mainwindow.ui

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ConectarDB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    ConectarDB.setHostName("localhost");
    ConectarDB.setDatabaseName("Banco");
    ConectarDB.setPort(3306);
    ConectarDB.setUserName("root");
    ConectarDB.setPassword("root");}
```

Works nice, but I have two questions:

1) How would I do to get a message confirming that the connection was successfully made, after the button was clicked?

2) Once connected, I have another form with a `comboBOX` in it.

```
Buscar_por_CURSO::Buscar_por_CURSO(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Buscar_por_CURSO)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mBuscaCurso = new QSqlTableModel(this);
    mBuscaCurso->setTable("Cursos");
    mBuscaCurso->select();
    ui->comboBox->setModel(mBuscaCurso);
}
```

My table Cursos:

```
Create table Cursos(
ID_curso int not null auto_increment,
Nome_curso varchar (50),
primary key (ID_curso)
)default charset = utf8;
```

That way, what appears in the comboBox are the **ID_curso**, but I would like it to be **Nome_curso**. How do I do that?

Comment: I used `QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel;
    model->setQuery("select nome_curso from Cursos");
    ui->comboBox->setModel(model);` to solve the problem number 2. But now, I'm thinking in use the **nome_curso** selected in the comboBox to query data from other table that have `foreign key (Curso_id) references Cursos (ID_Curso)` in a tableView widget. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

As per your second query
`ui->comboBox->setModel->setModelColumn('Nome_curso');`

should do the trick
For your 1st query
`QMessageBox(QMessageBox::Information, 'Connection Successfull', "Connection to database was successfull").exec();`